# Will ranked and unranked Greater Rift Keystones convert to new Greater Rift Keystones in v2.3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've learned that the following two changes will happen around rift keystones with the introduction of 2.3:

- Rift Keystones Fragments (for non-greater rifts) will be made useless. It no longer takes a keystone fragment to open a normal rift. Existing keystones in your inventory will become gray items that can be sold to a vendor for a little bit of cash.
- Greater rift keystones are introduced. The trial level is removed and you no longer require a ranked keystone to go to a particular rank. Instead you can choose the greater rift level you want to play when you interact with the obelisk.

My question is this:

What will happen to:

- Keystone of Trials
- Greater Rift Keystone

Will either or both of these convert to the new unranked keystone?

I'm assuming that PTR would answer this question but I am unable to install PTR for some reason otherwise I would've simply tried.

---

Why am I asking? I got a bit of rift keystone fragments but after running greater rifts to upgrade legendary gems I'm out of trial keystone and greater rift keystones. As such, if the greater rift related keystones from pre-2.3 convert to the new type afterwards I would simply do normal rift runs to grab as many greater rift keys as I can possibly get before 2.3 goes live.

---

**Note**: I am well aware of this sites stance on speculation around prerelease software. I am asking if information about this has already been posted as a fact, I'm not asking what people *think*. If no concrete information has been posted, simply post a comment and I'll delete the question myself.

Comment: Asking if something has been posted is the same as asking for the unreleased information in the first place.  That said, I believe the 2.3 PTR allows us to answer this.  So it is playable.

Comment: I have a ranked keystone, so I'm interested in what will happen :)

Comment: I think I found my answer posted by someone who has tested PTR - http://blizzardwatch.com/2015/07/04/diablo-3-patch-2-3-0-ptr/ - In short, nephalem rift keystones become gray, vendor-trash, whereas both trial keys and ranked greater rift keys are converted to the new unranked greater rift key. Which means I will play nephalem rifts tonight :)

Comment: 19 nephalem rifts later and I have 24 greater rift trial and ranked keys :) Still have 19 more rift keystone fragments so new bout tomorrow. Hope 2.3 comes soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the current [2.3.0 PTR Patch Notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19814212/patch-230-ptr-patch-notes-7-21-2015#am):

**About Nephalem Rifts and Keystones**

- Nephalem Rifts no longer require Keystones

**About Greater Rifts and Greater Rift Keystones**

- Generic Greater Rift Keystones now drop and can drop at any difficulty level
- The Realm of Trials has been removed from the game
- Greater Rift tiers are now selected via a dropdown menu
- Greater Rift tiers are now selected via a dropdown menu *(The maximum rift tier that can be selected is: Your previous best, or one tier higher than the highest Greater Rift you have successfully completed)*

---

**So to answer your question:**

- Your Rift Keystone Fragments will become garbage (as you'll no longer need them to enter a Nephalem Rift)
- Your Greater Rift Keystones, both ranked and trial keystones, will become the new unranked Greater Rift Keystones and you'll be able to select the level of your choice thanks to a dropdown menu

**The advised course of action to prepare for 2.3:**

- Use all your Rift Keystone Fragments to generate as many GR Keystones as you can to farm the new patch sets, etc, once the patch is live, plus you won't be bothered with the trials anymore
- Transform your current GR Keystones into too high leveled GR Keystones that you can't actually do (if your gems are too leveled up to consider that option) as they will be changed into generic GR Keystone that you will be able to farm again in 2.3

*Disclaimer: The PTR is of course subject to chance but I highly doubt these will be subject to change, as the feedback concerning the keystones  has only been positive on the PTR.*

Comment: You're almost there though, this article - http://blizzardwatch.com/2015/07/04/diablo-3-patch-2-3-0-ptr/ - verifies that existing greater rift keystones (trial and ranked) are both converted into the new unraked keystone. There is no point in me posting my own answer, just edit your answer to be correct and I will accept it.

Comment: You could also link to that article I posted link to in my comment above, verifies what your answer now reads.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That's what I've read from PTR related online articles (but as it's not blue post or official source I prefered to link the PTR patch note only). You're right for the Nephalem keystone though, it's just that the money earned through them is very much insignificant with torment X's arrival, and you'd be much better off transforming them.

Comment: Oh, definitely, they're both useless and relatively worthless as they are when 2.3 is live so I will definitely try to convert as many as I can into greater rift keystones.

Comment: Can this answer be updated please. I have no idea what a 'Nephalem Keystone' is and nor does the Diablo 3 Wikia. I have 'Rift Keystone Fragment', 'Keystone of Trails', and 'Greater Rift Keystone Rank n'